# Change css background-image with php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm doing a profile for this website, and I wanted to do a cover photo like element like facebook has. The problem I have ran into is, first how do I save the background image of the cover? Like, I can save the url of the image in the database, but how would I possibly be able to put it in css?

I do not really want to just put:

```
<div style="background-image:url(<?php echo $imageUrl?>) no-repeat center center fixed">
</div>
```

That looks really ugly markup. Is there some other way?

Comment: Save it under a predetermined name

Comment: As ugly as it is, it's the only realistic solution IMHO

Comment: _That looks really ugly markup._ - behind some swish web sites there's a whole pile of ugly. We use the tools we have.

Comment: I know we use the tools we have, and being a programmer, I have learned there is always the fugly way to do things, then then the right method to do things. I just can't figure out the right way for this one.

Comment: I would try to create a custom.css file with php for each user. It would need more http requests.

Comment: That's not efficient at all. JAL's answer seems to be a little bit more ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other options would be to put it in a style tag, or have php generate an external CSS file.

For the tag you'd do

```
<style>
  div { background-image: url(<?php echo $imageURL;?>); }
</style>
```

That is a bit cleaner than inline HTML styling.

Comment: This is indeed much cleaner, though, wouldn't it be heavier to load like this? I mean bringing css from a stylesheet and then rendering css from a `<style></style>` tag? I'm all for efficiency.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest having an external CSS file, though I did mention that possibility. Doing this method, an inline style tag, shouldn't be any less performant.