# how to pass PHP variable in bootstrap CCS class background image link for dynamic image changing in the background

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this CSS for FULL Background image. Now i want to pass PHP variable to this URL to change the background image dynamically. Plz let me know . my codes are..

```
.imgback {
padding-top:140px;
height:100vh;
min-height:400px;
background-size:cover;
background-image:url("../img/picmax/6.jpg");
}

<section class="imgback"> 
<div class="container"> 
<h1 class="text-center">Traveller's Zone.</h1>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inline or internal css as follow:

**Internal**

```
<style>
  div { background-image: url(<?php echo $imageURL;?>); }
</style>
```

**Inline**

```
<div style="background-image:url(<?php echo $imageUrl?>) no-repeat center center fixed">
</div>
```

[Reference from Change css background-image with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877311/change-css-background-image-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use php variable in your style code but must need to write css code after php variable . something like this

```
<?php
$bg_image = '../img/picmax/6.jpg'; // this is static value for test
?>
<section class="imgback">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Traveller's Zone.</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

and add style after define php value then you can use this code

```
<style>
        .imgback {
            padding-top: 140px;
            height: 100vh;
            min-height: 400px;
            background-size: cover;
            background-image: url("<?=$bg_image?>");
        }
    </style>
```

of you can use this php value in your html code

```
<?php
$bg_image = '../img/picmax/6.jpg';
?>
<section class="imgback" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $bg_image ?>')">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Traveller's Zone.</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load a data from database and place it inside everywhere you like.

```
`<?php
$a = "6.jpg";
?>`
```

then insert it into your css

```
.imgback {
padding-top:140px;
height:100vh;
min-height:400px;
background-size:cover;
background-image:url("../img/picmax/");
}

<section class="imgback"> 
<div class="container"> 
<h1 class="text-center">Traveller's Zone.</h1>
</div>
</section>
```

But that  won't be good enough because php only runs once on every *refresh or load*. (you can use **jQuery**) or you better use **JavaScript** for these type of works as because they are triggered by events so you can **change images without refreshing the page**